# prevent from double/triple SUMing when JOINing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i am joining two tables: `accn_demographics` and `accn_payments`. The relationship between the two tables is `one to many` between  `accn_demographics.accn_id` and `accn_payments.accn_id`

My question is when I am summing the PAID_AMT and COPAY_AMT, I am getting double/triple/quadrouple the number that I should be getting.

Is there an obvious problem with my `join` condition?

```
select sum(p.paid_amt) as SumPaidAmount
    , sum(p.copay_amt) as SumCoPay
    , p.pmt_date
    , d.load_Date
    , p.ACCN_ID
from  accn_payments p
join 
(
    select distinct load_date, accn_id 
    from accn_demographics
) d
    on p.ACCN_ID=d.ACCN_ID
where p.POSTED='Y'
    and p.pmt_date between '20120701' and '20120731'
group by p.pmt_date, d.load_Date,p.ACCN_ID
order by 3 desc
```

thanks so much for your guidance.

Comment: Are there multiple rows in accn_demographics with the same accn_id and different load_date values?

Comment: can you show sample data and expected output anywhere in SqlFiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the summation in a subquery:

```
select sum(p.SumPaidAmount) as SumPaidAmount, sum(p.SumCoPay) as SumCoPay,
       p.pmt_date, d.load_Date, p.ACCN_ID
from  (select accn_id, p.pmt_date, sum(paid_amt) as SumPaidAmt,
              sum(copay_amt) as SumCoPay
       from accn_payments p
       where p.POSTED='Y' and
             p.pmt_date between '20120701' and '20120731'
       group by accn_id, pmt_date
      ) p join
      (select distinct load_date, accn_id from accn_demographics) d
      on p.ACCN_ID=d.ACCN_ID
group by p.pmt_date, d.load_Date,p.ACCN_ID
order by 3 desc
```

Question:  do you really intend for pmt_date to be in the final results?  It looks like you want to remove it from both the outer SELECT and the subquery.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'accn_payments.ACCN_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'SumPaidAmount'.

Comment: i edited your query according to error msgs: 
 select sum(p.SumPaidAmt) as SumPaidAmount, sum(p.SumCoPay) as SumCoPay,
       p.pmt_date, d.load_Date, p.ACCN_ID
from  (select accn_id, p.pmt_date, sum(paid_amt) as SumPaidAmt,
              sum(copay_amt) as SumCoPay
       from accn_payments p
       where p.POSTED='Y' and
             p.pmt_date between '20120701' and '20120731'
             group by ACCN_ID,p.PMT_DATE
      ) p join
      (select distinct load_date, accn_id from accn_demographics) d
      on p.ACCN_ID=d.ACCN_ID
group by p.pmt_date, d.load_Date,p.ACCN_ID
order by 3 desc

Comment: and still getting the same result (oops very sorry for formatting)

Comment: Adding in the group by should fix that problem.  You are grouping by the load date and by the fields used for aggregation in the first subquery . . . I'm not seeing where the duplication might be occurring.  Can you modify your question with an example of data and the correct results that you want?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see if that `(select distinct load_date, accn_id from accn_demographics)` might return several matches.  Look at your data and run a separate query

```
select distinct load_date, accn_id from accn_demographics WHERE accn_id=SomeID
```

where `SomeID` is one of the result accounts that is returning double/triple values.  That should pinpoint your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's not so obvious for beginners. What happens is that for every `accn_payments` record, you're matching on ONLY the `accn_id`, which means if there are multiple records in `accn_demographics` for that particular `accn_id`, then you will get duplicate `accn_payment` records due to the join. Is there another limiting field on `accn_demographics` to join back to the payments?

Ultimately, think of it this way:

accn_payments (p):

```
accn_id    |    paid_amt    |    copay_amt    |  ...
----------------------------------------------------
1          |    100.00      |    20.00        |  ...
```

accn_demographics (d):

```
accn_id    |    load_date   |    ...
------------------------------------
1          |    2012/01/01  |    ...
1          |    2012/03/05  |    ...
1          |    2012/06/23  |    ...
```

After joining, your results will look like this:

```
p.accn_id | p.paid_amt | p.copay_amt | p... | d.accn_id | d.load_date | d...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 100.00     | 20.00       | .... | 1         | 2012/01/01  | ....
1         | 100.00     | 20.00       | .... | 1         | 2012/03/05  | ....
1         | 100.00     | 20.00       | .... | 1         | 2012/06/21  | ....
```

As you can see, the same row from `accn_payments` gets replicated for every matching `accn_demographics` record, since you specified only the `accn_id` column to be the join criteria. It can't limit the results any further, so it the DB engine says "Hey, look, this `p` record matches for all these `d` records, this must be what he was asking for!" Obviously not what was intended, as when you sum on the `p.paid_amt` and `p.copay_amt`, it performs a sum for ALL ROWS (even though they are duplicated).

Ultimately, see if you can limit the join criteria for `accn_demographics` even further (by some date, perhaps), that way you limit the number of duplicate payment records during the join.

Comment: Nice explanation.  Except the grouping criteria is by load_date.  These remain separate records in the final results.

Comment: Is it possibly that you have duplicate `pmt_date`s for a particular `accn_id` in your `accn_payments` table? What's the output of `SELECT accn_id, pmt_date, count(*) FROM accn_payments GROUP BY accn_id, pmt_date HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`?